# # pkg-config --cflags -- MagickWand MagickCore MagickWand MagickCore | Docker | golang:alpine AS build

Tags: docker, go

Am new to golang,
and I need to generate a thumbnail from pdf when I upload it.
am using ImageMagick with docker and golang.

But am getting challenged on building docker image including ImageMagick

**Docker set up**

```
FROM golang:alpine AS build

RUN apk --no-cache add gcc g++ make git

WORKDIR /go/src/app

COPY go.mod .

COPY go.sum .

RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o ./bin/web-app ./main.go

FROM alpine:3.13

RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates

WORKDIR /usr/bin

COPY --from=build /go/src/app/bin /go/bin

EXPOSE 1000

ENTRYPOINT /go/bin/web-app --port 1000
```

when I build my docker, am getting this error.

[image]

Please kindly help out on this.
Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Am trying to generate an image from pdf using ImageMagick,
and the package am using is 
"gopkg.in/gographics/imagick.v2/imagick"
but up is the error i keep getting.